# How to reference/return a value from SignalR?

Tags: python-3.x, signalr

This is the code I have:

```
from signalr_aio import Connection

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create connection
    # Users can optionally pass a session object to the client, e.g a cfscrape session to bypass cloudflare.

    connection = Connection('https://beta.bittrex.com/signalr', session=None)
    hub = connection.register_hub('c2')

    hub.server.invoke('GetAuthContext', API_KEY)               #Invoke 0 Creates the challenge that needs to be signed by the create_signature coroutine
    signature = await create_signature(API_SECRET, challenge)  #Creates the signature that needs to authenticated in the Authenticate query
    hub.server.invoke('Authenticate', API_KEY, signature)      #Invoke 1 authenticates user to account level information

    connection.start()
```

What I have to do is verify my identity by getting a string-type challenge by the `GetAuthContext` call, then create a string-type signature using that challenge, and then pass that signature to the `Authenticate`call. The problem I'm having is that that I need to enter the return value of the `GetAuthContext` into the challenge parameter of the `create_signature` coroutine. I'm guessing from the comment next to the below example that every invoke method gets marked as `I([index of method])`, so I would have to do `signature = await create_signature(API_SECRET, 'I(0)')`

```
async def on_debug(**msg):
    # In case of `queryExchangeState` or `GetAuthContext`
    if 'R' in msg and type(msg['R']) is not bool:
         # For the simplicity of the example I(1) corresponds to `Authenticate` and I(0) to `GetAuthContext`
         # Check the main body for more info.
         if msg['I'] == str(2):
            decoded_msg = await process_message(msg['R'])
            print(decoded_msg)
        elif msg['I'] == str(3):
            signature = await create_signature(API_SECRET, msg['R'])
            hub.server.invoke('Authenticate', API_KEY, signature)
```

Later this example gets assigned to connection.received ( `connection.received += on_debug` ) so I'm guessing that after `connection.start()` I have to put `connection.recieved()` to call the on_debug coroutine which will verify me, but for now I just want to understand how to reference the .invoke() methods to use within a function or coroutine.

Comment: Also, does anyone know how the response is structured from the .invoke() calls? The on_debug makes me think it's a dictionary and I'm sure it would help me understand this module a lot more if I knew how it was structured

Answer (score 0):

I am far from an expert, but the feed from Bittrex is indeed a Dictionary.

```
for i in range(0, len(decoded_msg['D'])):
  print('The Currency pair is:{0} the Bid is:{1} and the Ask is :{2}'.format(decoded_msg['D'][i]['M'], decoded_msg['D'][i]['B'], decoded_msg['D'][i]['A']))
```